# appdelegate how to pushViewController with storyboard

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard

In my app delegate I am pushing the user to a view controller if the user details are saved

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  
  // cached user
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser)
    {
        NSLog(@"current user signing and looking for VC %@", currentUser);
        // A user was cached, so skip straight to the main view

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        TaskSelectionViewController*viewController = [[TaskSelectionViewController alloc] initWithUser:currentUser];
        [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

                NSLog(@"VC found");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"VC not found");
    }
```

TaskSelectionViewController.m

```
 -(id)initWithUser:(PFUser *)currentUser
{
NSLog(@"current user %@", currentUser);

NSLog(@"task Selection initwithuser");
return self;
 }
```

The push is working but all I get is the NavigationController bar at the top and a black Screen.

what is missing ??

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK done using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID"

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
TaskSelectionViewController *controller = (TaskSelectionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"task"];
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes that's the way to go... I haven't seen you were using storyboards.

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't using the storyboard.

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    TaskSelectionViewController *controller = [[TaskSelectionViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

In the `-(id)initWithUser:(PFUser *)currentUser` of TaskSelectionViewController you should call `[super init]` or something similar to have your ViewController initialized properly. This solved a similar problem for me at least.

Look at Apple's examples for reference implementations of initialization methods of view controllers.